# Why is the time complexity of nested while loops in Quicksort not O(n^2)?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops, quicksort

```
def partition(l, h):
    i, j = l, h
    while i < j:
        while arr[l] > arr[i]:
            i += 1
        while arr[j] > arr[l] and j >= 0:
            j += 1
        if i < j:
            arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
    arr[l], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[l]
    return j
```

The time complexity of nested while loops is O(n<sup>2</sup>), the above snippet code is from Quicksort. Then how is the overall time complexity O(n log n)?

Comment: It's only O(n^2) if the loops at all levels execute n times. But the nested loops are processing smaller portions of the array, which makes it O(n log n).

Comment: Are you sure that this is `j += 1` and not `j -= 1`?

Comment: Quicksort is, in fact, O(n^2). It's only O(n lg n) in the *expected* case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code is buggy. The first inner `while` loop condition will never be true at the start, since `i` is equal to `l`, and so `i` will never be incremented, even after the values start getting moved around by the swap that happens at the end of the outer loop. I'm not sure this code is worth much analysis if it's not likely to work properly!

Comment: It is important to understand, the complexity of nested loops... depends on the specifics of the loops. Consider: `for i in range(10): for j in range(10): print(i*j)` is *constant time*

Answer (score 2):

The partition function takes linear time -- as the comments point out, the size of the list you're partition decreases, allowing for the possibility of an `O(n log n)` runtime.

However, quicksort runs in `O(n^2)` if your choice of partition point is poor. For example, consider the case when your partition chooses the largest element in the array that hasn't already been a partition. Then the runtime can be expressed as `T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(n) ==> O(n^2)`.

However, randomly choosing the partition gives an `O(n log n)` expected time. If you want an `O(n log n)` runtime in the worst-case, you can use a deterministic median finding algorithm, such as the one given in [these slides](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/andreas-klappenecker/csce411-s14/csce411-random3.pdf), to find a good partition. (These slides also give a formal proof of the expected runtime of randomized quicksort.)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that even in the O(N^2) case with bad pivots, the nested loops shown in the question's code are still only taking O(N) time, it's that they get repeated N more times that makes the overall algorithm O(N^2).

Comment: Edited into the original answer. Thanks for the suggestion.